# WLS Dynamic Cluster - JMS Store BEA-280077

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing, weblogic12c

I am trying to configure a application with WLS Dynamic Cluster which was previously running on single node.

When I felt I am done with all the required configuration and was able to create 4 nodes on the same machine and I was as well able to bring one node up, then I encountered below exception when I tried start 2nd node.

```
<May 25, 2016, 2:36:20,503 AM PDT> <Error> <Store> <BEA-280077> <JDBC store "JDBCStore-APP@Cluster-0-rer-5" in this server is not the owner of database table "JMSStore_WLStore". Unexpected current owner is "[name=(server=Cluster-0-rer-4!host=10.196.16.110!process=20634@server.com!domain=v12C_d!store=JDBCStore-APP@Cluster-0-rer-4!table=JMSStore_WLStore):random=-2378785191442816046:timestamp=1464168969899]", expected current owner is "[name=(server=Cluster-0-rer-5!host=10.196.16.110!process=22894@server.com!domain=v12C_d!store=JDBCStore-APP@Cluster-0-rer-5!table=JMSStore_WLStore):random=2022312961513516767:timestamp=1464168960044]".>

<May 25, 2016, 2:36:20,551 AM PDT> <Error> <Store> <BEA-280072> <JDBC store "JDBCStore-APP@Cluster-0-rer-5" failed to open table "JMSStore_WLStore".
weblogic.store.io.jdbc.OwnershipException: [Store:280064]280077 (server="Cluster-0-rer-5" store="JDBCStore-APP@Cluster-0-rer-5" table="JMSStore_WLStore")
```

The application has JMS Module, JMS Server, Persistence Store and Data Source all pointing to the nodes in clusters.

It looks obvious that the table 'JMSStore_WLStore' is current owned by the process of the node I started initially and when I start 2nd node above exception occurs.

Currently I am looking for ways to fix this issue and possible solution.
Will really appreciate any help on this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think your persistent store is not well configured. The table name should look like "*prefix_if_any_cluster_name_server_instance_id*_WLSTORE". Check that your store is targeted to the dynamic cluster and not on a per server basis. Please, also share the version of weblogic you are using.

Comment: yes the persistence store, jdbc store, jms server and jms module all target to Cluster. the WLS version is 12C.

Comment: 12.1.x or 12.2.1 ? 
Can you share your config.xml file ?

Comment: Ilan's comment is not relevant if you are realy using a dynamic cluster. In this situation, WebLogic ensures that tables are correctly named in the database.

Comment: really appreciate your following up on this... the release is 12.2.1 and yes I am using Dynamic Cluster which works on concept of server template.

Comment: the config.xml is huge..please let me know which portion of xml should i share

Comment: Can you post the setup of the cluster, the datasource and the persistent store from the config.xml file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112958/discussion-between-emmanuel-collin-and-leo11).